# Prove regular languages are closed under f(n) = 2^n and f(n) = n^2

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Suppose $ R $ is a regular language, let $ f(R) = \{ w \mid \exists x \text{ such that } |x| = f(|w|) \land wx \in R\}$, prove that $ f(R) $ is regular for $ f(n) = 2^n $ and for $ f(n) = n^2$. I've been on this question for a while now, and I'm not really sure how to approach it. I only really know elementary techniques like Myhill-Nerode and constructing DFA/regex, so I probably won't understand solutions using more complex logical models of regular languages.

Comment: A (somewhat technical) characterization of such functions where regularity holds is given in [Closure of regular languages are closed under certain cut operations](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f(n)=2^n$:

Let $M=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ be the DFA recognizing $R$. Denote by $\mathcal{G}$ the set of functions from $Q$ to $\mathcal{P}(Q)$ (where $\mathcal{P}(Q)$ means the power set of $Q$), and for any $g,h\in\mathcal{G}$, denote by $gh$ the function defined as $$gh(\cdot)=\bigcup_{q\in h(\cdot)}g(q).$$

Construct a new DFA $M'$ of whose states each is labeled a pair $(q,g)\in Q\times\mathcal{G}$. The transition function $\delta'$ of $M'$ is defined as

$$\delta'((q,g),a)=\left(\delta(q,a),gg\right),$$

for all $q\in Q, g\in\mathcal{G}, a\in\Sigma$. The start state of $M'$ is $(q_0,g_0)$ where $g_0$ is defined as $g_0(\cdot)=\{\delta(\cdot,a)\mid a\in \Sigma\}$. The set of accept states of $M'$ is $\{(q,g)\in Q\times\mathcal{G}\mid g(q)\cap F \neq \emptyset\}$.

Now we claim that

> After reading a word $w$, if $M$ reaches state $q$, then $M'$ reaches the state $(q,g)$, where $g(\cdot)$ represents the set of states $M$ can potentially reach when starting at state $\cdot$ then reading a word of length $f(|w|)$.

This cliam can be proven by mathematical induction on $|w|$. With this claim, we can see $M'$ indeed recognizes $f(R)$.

---

For $f(n)=n^2$, the proof is similar. In this case, each state of $M'$ is labeled a tuple $(q,g_1,g_2)\in Q\times \mathcal{G}^2$, the transition function becomes

$$\delta'((q,g_1,g_2),a)=\left(\delta(q,a),g_1g_0,((g_2g_1)g_1)g_0\right),$$

where $g_0(\cdot)=\{\delta(\cdot,a)\mid a\in \Sigma\}$ as above, the start stae becomes $(q_0,I,I)$ where $I(\cdot)=\{\cdot\}$, and the set of accept states becomes $\{(q,g_1,g_2)\in Q\times\mathcal{G}\mid g_2(q)\cap F \neq \emptyset\}$.

Also, our claim becomes

> After reading a word $w$, if $M$ reaches state $q$, then $M'$ reaches the state $(q,g_1,g_2)$, where $g_1(\cdot),g_2(\cdot)$ respectively represent the set of states $M$ can potentially reach when starting at state $\cdot$ then reading a word of length $|w|,|w|^2$.

Comment: Wow that's really clever way to sort of make the DFA "remember" |w|. I was under the impression that an approach like this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

$f(R)$ is regular since it can be decided by a one-tape TM in linear time.

Do a constant-sized matrix multiplication inside the TM's finite control.

The DFA transition can be viewed as a 0-1 matrix $A$ by forgetting the arc label. First comput $A^n$, then bounce back to compute $A^{n^2}$. Then proceed to run the DFA as usual to know the last state it ends after finishing readinv $x$. Query the computed $A^{n^2}$.

Similarly for $2^n$.

Comment: The language $\{a^nb^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ can be decided by a one-tape TM in linear time but it is not a regular language.

Comment: Nope, it is impossible to decide that language by a one-tape TM in linear-time. You are confused with the two-tape one. This is exactly the proof of non-linear lowerbound for that language. In fact, an $\Omega(n^2)$ lowerbound for one-tape can be proved. For 2-tape, you can do it in $O(n\log(n))$.

Comment: And you are repeating my idea in details in your answer. Ok, more TeX typesettings may get accepted easier.

Comment: You are right DFA = linear time TM but the proof seems a bit tricky. In addition $\{a^n b^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ can be decided by a one-tape TM in $O(n\log n)$ by moving the counter in the tape.

Answer (score 0):

For this and similar problems you need to first prove a property of finite state machines: The set of lengths of strings that transition from one state to another is either a finite set of integers, or there is a k >= 1, and two finite sets X and Y such that every possible length is either in X, or is equal to n*k + y, where n >= 0 and y is an element of Y.

Second, if we know the lengths of all inputs going from state S to a fixed accepting state T, can we determine the set of integers k, such that after going from initial state to S, we can reach the accepting state after a total of f(n) steps?

As an example, if we took k steps from initial state to S,and there are 7j + 15 steps needed to reach an accepting state, and f(n)= n^2 then n^2 mod 7 = 0,1,4,2,2,4,1 so k+7j+15 = n^2 If k mod 7 is 7, 0 or 3.

And here it is essential that not only can we solve this for k, but the solution is easy enough that we can modify our stat machine to handle it.